# CA Rally - How to get child object details, like from ProjectPermission get Project details

Tags: javascript, rally

I am building a grid to show the Project Permissions with the Project details.

I am able to get users and Project permission details using

```
   Ext.create("Rally.data.wsapi.Store", {
                 model: "ProjectPermission",
```

But I cannot get Project details. How can I get the project detials using ProjectPermission..

```
_.each(results, function(result) {

                 if (result.get("User").UserName) {

                     var permission = {
                         UserName: result.get("User").UserName,
                         DisplayName: result.get("User").DisplayName,
                         EmailAddress: result.get("User").EmailAddress,
                         ProjectName: result.get("Project")._refObjectName,
                         Role: result.get("Role"),
                         Disabled: result.get("User").Disabled,

                         Status: result.get("Project").State /*Not able to get this*/
                     };
                     permissions.push(permission)
                 }
```

Really appriciate your help.

For reference, This is the Model Structure, need to get project details using _ref

```
"ProjectPermission":{
"_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
"_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
"_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission/152079079u71479826p1",
"_refObjectUUID": "",
"_objectVersion": "0",
"_refObjectName": "LTC CS Portal Viewer",
"CreationDate": null,
"_CreatedAt": "today at 4:30 pm",
"ObjectID": null,
"ObjectUUID": "null",
"VersionId": "0",
"Subscription": null,
"CustomObjectID": "152079079u71479826p1",
"Name": "LTC CS Portal Viewer",
"Role": "Viewer",
"User":{
"_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
"_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
"_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/152079079",
"_refObjectUUID": "6d44a99b-c235-45b7-b24e-add15e7108f8",
"_refObjectName": "Satish Pasala",
"_type": "User"
},
"Project":{
"_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
"_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
"_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/71479826",
"_refObjectUUID": "91bac7a9-6fc3-4a90-9bb9-fa341e08dae5",
"_refObjectName": "LTC CS Portal",
"_type": "Project"
},
"Workspace": null,
"Errors":[],
"Warnings":[]
}
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: Status: result.get("Project").State is Blank

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the project fields onto your fetch.  It looks like you want state from the comments above?

```
fetch: [
    'Project', 
    'State', 
    //...other project fields here
]
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, I did it but its showing undefined in console.log or in Grid

Comment: I even tried, but its giving error prjPerm.load is not a function

var prjPerm = result.getCollection("Project", {fetch:["State"]});
                            prjPerm.load({

Comment: You shouldn't have to load any collection.  Once you add State to your fetch on your original store your result.get('Project').State should work.  Also I'm pretty sure closed projects are not returned from WSAPI, so the value of all of them will likely be 'Open'.